# How can I scan SSH ports reliably on Windows XP using Java?

Tags: java, tcp, windows-xp

I maintain a tool for deploying software to embedded devices. These devices are detected by constantly scanning a range of IP addresses for anything answering on port 22, then opening an SSH connection to that port.

On Linux and Windows 7 this process works well with 20 threads and timeout of 500ms on the socket connect.

Unfortunately some of our users are still bound to Windows XP, where these settings do not work at all. A single thread with 3000ms timeout seems to work reliably, increasing the threads to two or setting the timeout to 1000ms causes consistent failure to detect anything - all attempts to connect time out (SocketTimeoutException).

We tried applying the [Event ID 4226 Patcher](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/windows-xp-sp2-tcpipsys-connection-limit-patch-1497) on one of the machines, but that did not help. We can not see these event in the logs either.

What is causing this behaviour and is there any way I can fix this?

**EDIT**: The actual code used to connect is this:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, 22), PORT_SCAN_TIMEOUT);
    LOGGER.trace("Someone is listening on {}:22", address);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.trace("Failed scan on {}", address, t);
    reschedule(address);
    continue;
}
```

If this connection succeeds, then a completely new one is created using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). In the failure scenario the code never gets beyond this initial attempt. All exceptions logged are SocketTimeoutExceptions.

**EDIT 2**:

I tried going one level lower in the stack and just check if the host is there, not the server socket, replacing above code with this:

```
try {
    if(!InetAddresses.forString(address).isReachable(PORT_SCAN_TIMEOUT)) {
        LOGGER.trace("{} not reachable", address);
        reschedule(address);
        continue;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.warn("Error trying to check host presence on {}, we will try to connect", e, address);
}
```

Even this fails if run by multiple threads or fast, but works with a single thread and 3000 ms timeouts. A command line ping against the host returns successful straight away (which is going to be my fallback solution now).

**EDIT 3**:

And with this it works as expected (obviously on Windows only):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "-n", "1", address);
try {
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor();
    return process.exitValue() == 0;
} catch (Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to spawn ping process", t);
    return false;
}
```

Given the small number of affected machines I'll use this, triggered by a magic system property toggle. I'd still appreciate any advice on why the first two approaches might fail.

Comment: Not enough information. Without knowing a lot more details about the devices and the network architecture, and what steps you've taken to debug the issue (Wireshark network traces, etc),  _"consistent failure to detect anything"_ is insufficient for anyone to help you.

Comment: There are so many possible factors here - but we don't even have a clue how you are doing your scanning. Given that you use Java, your options are limited, but we still should not try to guess how you do it.

Comment: @JimGarrison: the initial question already said that I see SocketTimeoutExceptions, but I added some more detail. I'll see if I can run Wireshark on any of the affected machines.

Comment: Wireshark doesn't show anything at all - I assume that's normal since there's no actual payload send.

Comment: Wireshark should show SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK, or RST packets for each connection attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Windows XP constrains the number of connections a single process can make. The solution for me was to apply the registry changes described on [the nmap page for Windows](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html). Afterwards the program behaves as expected.